# I am searching for a minimum in a matrix for every row

Tags: r

I have a matrix in R:

[,1] [,2] [,3]

"7"  "8" "0"...

And I want to have the minimum value of EVERY row of my matrix without zero. 
For example: In row 1 we have the values 7,8 and 0. The result should be 7.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Please see the following post on [creating a minimum example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 2):

We can use `rowMins` from `matrixStats` after `replace`ing the '0' value with `NA` and then use the `na.rm=TRUE` to get the expected minimum value per row.

```
library(matrixStats)
rowMins(replace(m1, m1==0, NA), na.rm =TRUE)
```

---

Or if we are using `base R`

```
apply(m1, 1, FUN = function(x) min(x[x!=0]))
```

Or another option is `pmin` after converting to `data.frame`

```
do.call(pmin, c(as.data.frame(replace(m1, m1==0, NA)), na.rm = TRUE))
```

#### data

```
m1 <- matrix(c(7, 4, 5, 8, 3, 0, 0, 1, 4), ncol=3)
```